# Dot Net Core 2.2 Sign Out behavior

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, azure-active-directory

Have .Net Core 2.2 MVC application and integrated with Azure AD for userAzure AD. User authentication and sign out is working as expected.

But if we copy the cookies AspNetCore.AzureADCookie, .AspNetCore.AzureADCookieC1, .AspNetCore.AzureADCookieC2 from the authenticated browser session using the EditThisCookie extension and logout then if we import again those copied cookies back into browsers and we are able to access the application. Application trusting the application and login automatically.

I'm using NuGet Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI NuGet package

Is this behavior expected?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the permissions and authentication configurations that you have set for the users within your Azure AD tenant and within the application. If the users are members of your Azure AD tenant or of your application and you've set up SSO using an MSAL library like OpenID Connect, then their credentials might be stored and they can log in by default.

Are you trying to say that you do not want your users to be able to one-click SSO with their pre-authenticated credentials?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-authentication-for-federated-users-portal?view=azurermps-5.7.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

Comment: Why it’s allowed for SSO When user explicitly logged out of app in the first place?